# how to find a cryptography scheme (either authentication or encryption) for which some formal analysis of security has not been done yet

Tags: cryptography

I have a project in Cryptography where I have to discuss the provable security of any proposed scheme (encryption or authentication) which has not been discussed yet.

Any pointers on how and where to start?

I tried researching some schemes but I could not find any scheme for which any security analysis has not been already done.

How can I find a scheme for which the security analysis might not have been formally proved? I am need of a starting point.

Thanks

Comment: Here you go:  [SKCJJU-256](http://www.skcjju256.com/).  Have fun!

Comment: thanks Xander.i looked at the algorithm. But the project is   more focused on schemes like cbc or counter. And we have to prove security in terms of plaintext or ciphertext attack. SKCJJU-256 is an algorithm like AES. Also its more of an individual effort but not published in any of the conferences. I am limited on the approach. I cannot analyse something that has not been published or not being used in any practical product. Thanks though. I will keep looking.

Comment: I don't believe you will find a published/presented/used crypto scheme that has not had any formal analysis performed on it.  A researched wouldn't publish/present a scheme without being able to prove it's usefulness.  Similarly, a product wouldn't use it if no analysis had been performed.

Comment: yes..thats the dilemma we are facing..anything not proved secure cannot be used..we are looking at RFCs...lets see if anything is available...

Comment: @Xander I'm having trouble making heads or tails of that site, but it looks sorta like a Vigenere cipher, which has had _extensive_ analysis done.

Comment: What about [SQRL](https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm)? This is a quite new authentication scheme, only about a year or so old. It involves both authentication and encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the Cryptology ePrint Archive:

http://eprint.iacr.org/

Comment: thanks Fred..will look at these too..looks like an extensive list..thanks

Answer (score 0):

guys thanks for your suggestions..
i finally went with the XBC paper from NIST website..
the project went just fine...
one funny thing i would like to share..
we had to present our work for the class and nothing was known about who would present which topic..as it turned out our topic was shared between 5 teams..including my team...this we got to know just minutes before the presentation started...
and our TA was smart enough to put all these presentations one after another...
so in the end we went on to repeat same stuff for almost half an hour..

thanks again guys

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. Please post an answer to your question and mark it as an answer. What did you do to find crypto schemes that had not been formally reviewed?

Answer (score 0):

Well for the project I selected XBC (cross block chaining) scheme which was submitted to NIST this year in may.
It was difficult to find a scheme for which security analysis had not been done..
we had few resources to our avail..NIST site, RFCs submitted over the years, security conferences...
We had to look at almost every paper for security analysis of the schemes...
This paper on XBC was present in the modes of development section in NIST...

This scheme is mostly like CBC with two IVs...author presented two algorithms...
XBC-1 was combo of CBC and CFB schemes
XBC-2 was combo of CBC and OFB schemes..
Author laid emphasis on the two man rule where IVs can be given to two men for enhanced security...Although the security of XBC relied on the choice of IVs...

In our project we showed how predictable IVs can lead to chosen plaintext attack..
Also keeping IVs as random, chosen ciphertext attack is possible..
In the end we concluded that it was not better than CBC and had security properties like CBC only..

Comment: Hi @Prabhendu Pandey and welcome on Stackoverflow. Your resolution is very welcome, however, it is not a real answer. It is your outcome to the search, whereas the question asks for sources. Consider posting this as new, edited part of your question.